# S3 AWS download Speed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm having troubles with downloading files from S3, If I download a file like 200MB, and then i download another files, the download speed it's just really slow like (40KB/s) as you can see in the follow pic:
[image: download speed]

And when the first download finish, the second continues with the 40KB/s...

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon S3 has ***huge*** bandwidth.

If you are downloading from Amazon S3 to your own computer (outside of AWS), then the only limitations that would impact you are your own Internet bandwidth, and any speed limitations imposed within your own network.

Comment: This is not the only reason! If you have millions of log files in your bucket it will impact the speed of downloads! I've been through this when enabling logs went wrong and we went from 20MB/s to 3MB/s on the same fiber-optic bandwidth. (it went back to normal once we remove all the small log files and set the path to another S3 bucket)

Answer (score 0):

I will presume that you are downloading an object **from Amazon S3 to an Amazon EC2 instance** in the same region as the S3 bucket.

In this scenario, the only bandwidth limitation is the **Network Performance** on the Amazon EC2 instance. Basically, the bigger the instance, the more bandwidth is available.

In the **Launch** screen, a `t2.large` is listed as **Low to Moderate** Network Performance. This is reasonably good, but not as good as larger instance types.

See:

- [Amazon EC2 Instance Configuration - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html)
- [EC2 Network Performance Cheat Sheet | cloudonaut](https://cloudonaut.io/ec2-network-performance-cheat-sheet/)

It might also be a result of the **software** you are using to download the files and how it multi-tasks and shares network bandwidth between the downloads.

Comment: Hi John, i'm downloading the files directly from S3 Manager(s3.console.aws.amazon.com) from the website. And if they share de network bandwidth why when the first download finish the second one don't take all the speed? Other thing, the S3 now is global,does not require region.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling **Transfer acceleration**
in bucket's **Properties**

Answer (score -1):

If you're connected to the Internet via WiFi router from your laptop, try to use cable connection instead.